# android-Filling the screen with a series of textView and buttons

Tags: android

In my code I want to have the following:

```
<LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout>
<Button>
</LinearLayout>
<TextView>
<TextView>
<TextView>
<TextView>
<LinearLayout>
<Button>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Whare the packing is horizontal (from left to right)

I the textView's changes during the code and I want the left and right button position to be fixed to the leftmost and rightmost of the screen. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Set the Button property android:gravity="left" or android:gravity="right"

Answer (score 0):

Use layout_weight to make the textviews expand to take up all available space, which will push the buttons to the edges, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  >
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <Button
      android:id="@+id/btnLeft"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Left"
    />
    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/widget36"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="TV1"
      android:layout_weight="1"
    />
    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/TV2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="TV2"
      android:layout_weight="1"
    />
    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/TV3"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="TV3"
      android:layout_weight="1"
    />
    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/TV4"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="TV4"
      android:layout_weight="1"
    />
    <Button
      android:id="@+id/btnRight"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Right"
    />
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```